# rule-based model out of a binary features dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, boosting

I have the following problem. I've been given a dataset where the features are binary which can be interpret as seen or not seen. The target value is categorical.

My goal is to generate a list of rules. For example:

$${v_1, v_3, v_4} \mapsto y_1 $$

One idea I had in mind is to train a logistic regression model (One versus all) and use the coefficients to determine which features affect the classification.

In other words, for each $y_i$ we train a model to find the $k$ best coefficients. I can go over that list of sorted coefficients and build a subset of features with the preferred accuracy.

The problem is that I think it's not a complete solution. With this methodology I can create only one rule essentially but there can be two (even distinct) subsets of features that maps to the same $y_i$.

What could be a better approach?

Maybe even a brute-force approach could be applied?

Comment: apply a tree classification algorithm, then you have to extract the rules by following the nodes of the tree.  perhaps some software does this automatically

Comment: @seanv507, thanks. Do you think boosting/bagging can be used too?

Comment: That depends on *your use case*. If you want simple rules then I would presume you would want a single tree.  boosting /bagging is combining 100s of trees..so I imagined it would not be suitable for you.